# Хочу реализовать следующий функционал: При нажатии на кнопку запустить, появляется модальное окно (html, js, jinja2, bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, bootstrap5

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
                            onclick="openModal()">
                            Запустить
                        </button>

                        <script>
                            let isOpen = false;

                            function openModal() {
                                isOpen = true;
                            }
                        </script>

                        {% if isOpen == true %}
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Заголовок модального окна</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Закрыть"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Понял</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
```

При выполнении кода, появляется ошибка: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'isOpen'. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `isOpen` -- не определена в контексте jinja.

Comment: А как определить isOpen в контексте?

Comment: Если речь о Вашей переменной которую Вы определяете таким образом `let isOpen = false;` внутри `script` тега и ожидаете что это все каким-то образом будет работать, то работать не будет, так как jinja генерирует HTML-код на сервере до того, как страница будет отправлена клиенту, а то что завернуто в `script` как раз отрабатывает на клиенте. Вообще просто уберите проверку, к чему она там?